# Watchdog: How to monitor a filesystem where multiple users deposit files?

Tags: python, watchdog

I want to watch for file changes in a directory. Multiple users can put files in this directory. I've tried setting up a watcher using two Python libraries: watchdog and watchfiles.

When I start the watcher on directory /a/b/c, I notice that it only triggers an event when files are created by me. If another user puts a file in /a/b/c, no such event is generated. Is there a way to detect such changes? Basically I want to detect all files created in /a/b/c regardless of user.

I'm working on Suse Enterprise Linux v12, service pack 5.

Comment: What is your code ? How are files uploaded there ? Manually ? is it a FTP or just a shared file system with manual access ?